# Telerik GridHyperlinkColumn's NavigateUrl is always one index off?

Tags: vb.net, hyperlink, telerik, radgrid

currently I am trying to use this databind method to assign the NavigateURL property of a radgrid gridhyperlinkcolumn for each row. Unfortunately, for each row, the link is set as the system key of the row previous.
So if these are my rows:

- SystemName|SystemKey
- Sys1|1
- Sys2|2
- Sys3|3

Sys1 will have no link,
Sys2 will have a link to ~/System.aspx?Key=1
and Sys3 will have a link to ~/System.aspx?Key=2
I've gathered that it's likely setting the NavigateURL property after the row's url has already been set and therefore only affects the next row? So how do I set this property properly?

Current Code:

```
Protected Sub rg_Systems_ItemDataBound(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As GridItemEventArgs) Handles rg_Systems.ItemDataBound
        If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
            Dim col As GridHyperLinkColumn = rg_Systems.MasterTableView.GetColumn("SystemName")
            Dim item As GridDataItem = e.Item
            Dim newUrl As String = "~/System.aspx?Key=" & item.GetDataKeyValue("SystemKey").ToString()
            col.NavigateUrl = newUrl
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do this without code-behind:

```
<telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn 
    DataTextField="SystemName"
    DataNavigateUrlFields="SystemKey" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/System.aspx?Key={0}">
</telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
```